# Can I restrict which IP address can access objects in a bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My organisation intends to provide data to 3rd parties by putting that data into files in a GCS bucket and granting the 3rd party's GCP service account access to the data. We want to lock down that access as much as possible, one thing we'd especially like to do is limit the IP addresses that are allowed to issue requests to get the data.

I have been pouring over IAM conditions documentation:

- [Overview of IAM Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview)
- [Attribute reference for IAM Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-attribute-reference#request)

however I'm not able to understand the docs in sufficient detail to know if what I want to do is possible.

I read this which sounded promising:

> The access levels attribute is derived from attributes of the request, such as the origin IP address, device attributes, the time of day, and more.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-attribute-reference#access-levels

but it seems as though that only applies when IAP is being used:

> The access levels attribute is available only when you use Identity-Aware Proxy

Is there a way to restrict which IP addresses can be used to access data in a GCS bucket?

Comment: Do you want to combine IAM and IP check? or to use only IP check (with any permission check on Cloud Storage)? Does it possible to use only IAM with IP filtering? If no, why? what is the risk that you want to cover?

Comment: Yes I think we want to combine IAM & IP checks. You ask "Does it possible to use only IAM with IP filtering?" and that's kinda why I'm here, to discover options like this (if indeed such an option exists). The risk we want to cover is that the credentials fall into the wrong hands, so we want to restrict the IP addresses that the credentials can be used from.

Answer (score 2):

*I just tested something that I never tried, and finally it works!*

So, to achieve this, you need 3 things

- Your bucket secured with IAM
- [HTTPS Load Balancer with](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets)

  - Your Bucket as backend bucket
  - A HTTPS frontend
  - A domain name, with your DNS A record configured on the Load Balancer IP
- [Cloud Armor policy](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies)

  - Create a edge policy
  - Default rule: deny all
  - Additional rule: all IP ranges (use /32 range for a specific IP)
  - Add the policy on your backend bucket

Let that cooking (about 10 minutes to let the load balancer dispatching its configuration, the certificate generation if you use a managed certificates,...)

Then, the requester can perform GET request to the bucket object, with the access token in the authorization header, something like that

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>" https://<DomainName>/path/to/object.file
```

Comment: hugely appreciate this Guillaume, thank you. Unfortunately I'm not sure that this works in our case because we do require the requester to authenticate using a GCP service account, the reason being that the requester is using Snowflake to access the data and we want to enable the scenario outlined at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-gcs-config.html, which requires a service account . I feel bad given the effort you've put in to fashioning a solution, I really do appreciate your efforts on my behalf.

Comment: Hmm, understood... Maybe ask the Snowflake support if there is a trick to replace gs:// by https:// and still use the service account key file to add the security header in the GET request. Or use BigQueyr!! :-p

Comment: BQ not an option unfortunately  :) (which is a shame because all the data we're sending originates from BQ - I've built a Cloud Function + Scheduler solution that exports the data to GCS). The requester is a partner organisation that runs Snowflake.

Comment: Your use case is interesting. If you have the possibility to ask Snowflake about the BigQuery Storage API usage, it could be interesting for you!! (Direct connection from Snowflake to the BigQuery data without an export function as you do.)

Comment: Just added an answer that I think will work here. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I’ve just found something that will work - VPC service perimeters. I’ve tried it and it does seem just what I need.

This blog post covers it very very well https://medium.com/google-cloud/limit-bucket-access-in-google-cloud-storage-by-ip-address-d59029cab9c6